# BASH: Is there any way to cut string returned by function using shell expansion tricks?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

What i have:

```
MUSTBE_TIME=`GetPastHours $[$i-1]|cut -c 1-2`
```

It works. But is there away to do something like this ?

```
MUSTBE_TIME=${`GetPastHours $[$i-1]`:1:2}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try an variation of `$ a=kalle && echo ${a:1:2}` read more about parameter expansion in [man bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Thought of sharing one more link which I always use http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 1):

(Incidentally, `$[...]` is an obsolete syntax; you should use `$((...))` instead.)

`bash` doesn't allow nesting of parameter expansions, you can can't use the result of a command substitution as if it were a parameter. You can use a combination of the `read` command and process substitution, though.

```
read -n 2 MUSTBE_TIME < <(GetPastHours $((i-1)))
```

Comment: I'm a fan of `read` and `process substitution` as well but it would also be good to consider simply using two lines of command substitution and a form of parameter expansion over it as it's faster (not needing to open a named pipe or something in `/dev/fd`) and redirecting input from it. Process substitution is also not supported in systems without named pipes or `/dev/fd/*`: `__=$(GetPastHours "$((i - 1))"); MUSTBE_TIME=${__:0:2}`

Comment: Named pipes are part of the POSIX standard, so some form of process substitution should be available. I omitted the two-step answer because I though Fredrik Pihl might post his comment as an answer.

Comment: Yes but at least in Cygwin they aren't possible as far as I could remember.

Comment: The question is tagged 'linux' and 'unix', so I'm not concerned about Windows.